# asp.net C# check value of multiple DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net, dropdown

I made a search button that will show data from sql to gridview, the search button is connected with DropDownList that contain two values (yes)and(no), so if user selected (yes) it should get the data where the value equals (yes) and the same thing with (no). this works with me fine I do eatch one seperated, but if I searched for both DropDownList at once it give me the first DropDownList right but the second one wrong, for example if DropDownList1 = "yes" show (yes) value and if DropDownList2 = "no" show (no) value, it will return (yes) for both of them,

here is my code:

```
 if (DropDownList_laptop.SelectedValue == "1")
    {
        // ... code here
   SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM emp_table where inv_lap = 'yes'";
    }
    else if (DropDownList_laptop.SelectedValue == "2")
    {
        // ... code here
   SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM emp_table where inv_lap = 'no'";
    }

    else if (DropDownList_pc.SelectedValue == "1")
    {
        // ... code here
   SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM emp_table where inv_pc = 'yes'";
    }
    else if (DropDownList_pc.SelectedValue == "2")
    {
        // ... code here
    SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM emp_table where inv_pc = 'no'";
    }
```

dropdown code:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList_laptop" runat="server" Height="29px" Width="70px">
                        <asp:listitem text="" value="0"></asp:listitem>
                        <asp:listitem text="yes" value="1"></asp:listitem>
                        <asp:listitem text="no" value="2"></asp:listitem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: else if (DropDownList_pc.SelectedValue == "1") in this line why there is an "else if" instead of only if?

Comment: What is the relation between `SqlDataSource1` and `DropDownList1` or `DropDownList2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something like this should work for you:

```
    string command = "SELECT * FROM emp_table";
    
    if (DropDownList_laptop.SelectedValue == "1"){
        command += " WHERE inv_lap = 'yes'";
    }
    else if (DropDownList_laptop.SelectedValue == "2")
    {
        command += " WHERE inv_lap = 'no'";
    }

    if (DropDownList_pc.SelectedValue == "1")
    {
        command += " AND inv_pc = 'yes'";
    }
    else if (DropDownList_pc.SelectedValue == "2")
    {
        command += " AND inv_pc = 'no'";
    }
    
    SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = command;
```

Comment: but I needed to add something to make it work perfectly because if used your code it will give me error if I only selected DropDownList_pc, so to solve this I needed to add where to string command value, so the rest conditions can have only AND,

Answer (score 0):

Look at the logic of the code behind. You are using if-elseif-elseif etc. That means that the first condition that gets met will get triggered and any further conditional clause won't. So you want to separate the if conditions relating to the separate dropdowns into separate if clauses.

```
if (DropDownList_laptop.SelectedValue == "1")
{
  SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM emp_table where inv_lap = 'yes'";
}
else if (DropDownList_laptop.SelectedValue == "2")
{
  SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM emp_table where inv_lap = 'no'";
}

// separate dropdown, separate logic!
if (DropDownList_pc.SelectedValue == "1")
{
  SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM emp_table where inv_pc = 'yes'";
}
else if (DropDownList_pc.SelectedValue == "2")
{
  SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM emp_table where inv_pc = 'no'";
}
```